Adding an interherited class from a different assembly by using a discriminator, and then retrieve it
I'm facing the following situation: I'm creating an agenda with a AgendaItemModel that is created in a assembly called AgendaModule. You can assume this assembly is being used, but there is another assembly which is optional: RepeatingAgendaModule which holds
a class RepeatingAgendaItemModel  that inherits from the AgendaItemModel.
Important to notice is that the AgendaModule doesn't know anything about the RepeatingAgendaModule (the other way around, of course, the RepeatingAgendaModule will know about the AgendaModule since it  inherits from AgendaItemModel).
I try to combine the AgendaItemModel and RepeatingAgendaItemModel in the same database table by using a specific discriminator for each since they both hold the same properties (only the execution for the RepeatingAgendaItemModel should happen in the RepeatingAgendaModule, hence no additional properties).
But when I retrieve all AgendaItemModel objects in the AgendaModule, I also want to retrieve the RepeatingAgendaItemModel objects despite the fact these objects are not known and than shown them in the agenda in the client (the main purpose of what I am trying to accomplish).
TLDR; from a separate module I'm trying to add a inherited object (by using a discriminator) to the table of its base type and then retrieve it.
Now I've tried to add this as follows (but running a migration doesn't cause the derived types to be added):
public class AgendaContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<AgendaItemModel>()
           .HasDiscriminator<string>("Discriminator")
           .HasValue<AgendaItemModel>("AgendaItemModel");
        AddDerivedTypes(modelBuilder);
    }
    
    private void AddDerivedTypes(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
       var baseType = typeof(AgendaItemModel);
       var assemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();
       var derivedTypes = assemblies.SelectMany(assembly => assembly.GetTypes()).Where(t => t != baseType && baseType.IsAssignableFrom(t));

       foreach (var type in derivedTypes)
       {
          var entityTypeBuilder = modelBuilder.Entity(type);
        modelBuilder.Entity<AgendaItemModel>().HasDiscriminator<string>("Discriminator").HasValue(type, type.Name);
       }
    }
}

And in the RepeatingAgendaModule:
public class RepeatingAgendaContext : AgendaContext
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<RepeatingAgendaItemModel>()
            .HasBaseType<AgendaItemModel>()
            .HasDiscriminator<string>("Discriminator")
            .HasValue<RepeatingAgendaItemModel>("RepeatingAgendaItemModel");
    }
}

When I try to retrieve the AgendaItemModel objects that are in the database I get the following exception:

'System.InvalidOperationException' in Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational.dll: 'Unable to materialize entity instance of type 'RepeatingAgendaItemModel'. No discriminators matched the discriminator value 'RepeatingAgendaItemModel'

Despite the fact that the loop seems to find these discriminator in the AddDerivedTypes.
Any help would be much appreciated, I've been stuck on this for quite a while!

This one should be called by other overload : modelBuilder.Entity("YourNamespace.RepeatingAgendaItemModel").HasDiscriminator<string>("Discriminator").HasValue(type, type.Name);
